# jQuery mobile build listview in another page and navigate there

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

This is a simple Cordova & jQuery mobile (1.4.5) app...

When I click on an item in a listview I want to dinamically build a listview on another page and navigate there.

The code I have works as desired as long as I don't click items/buttons too quickly. If I navigate between pages back and forth quickly then sooner or later I end up with an empty page, with the wrong text in header.

This happens both in Ripple and in actual Android device. Why? how can I avoid this? I think it is related to clicking items during page transition but I don't know.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <a href="#categories" class="ui-btn mainButton">Exercises</a>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="categories">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Go back">
        <h1>Categories</h1>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="categoryList"></ul>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="exercises">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Go back">
        <h1 id="category"></h1>
    </div>

    <ul data-role="listview" id="exerciseList"></ul>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var lastCategoryID;

$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {

    switch (data.toPage[0].id) {
        case "categories":
            createCategories();
            break;
        case "exercises":
            createExercises(event.target.id, $(event.target).text());
            break;
    }
});    

function createExercises(categoryID, categoryName) {

    //Don't rebuild if is same category of last time.
    if (lastCategoryID == categoryID) return; else { lastCategoryID = categoryID; }

    //Set header text.
    $("#category").text(categoryName);

    $("#exerciseList").empty();
    switch (categoryID){
        case "c0":
            $("#exerciseList").append('<li><a href="#exercise" id="e0">Warming up</a></li>');
            $("#exerciseList").append('<li><a href="#exercise" id="e1">Weight lifting</a></li>');
            break;
        case "c1":
            $("#exerciseList").append('<li><a href="#exercise" id="e0">Warming up</a></li>');
            $("#exerciseList").append('<li><a href="#exercise" id="e2">Running</a></li>');
            break;
    }
    $("#exerciseList").listview("refresh");
}

function createCategories() {
    $("#categoryList").empty();
    $("#categoryList").append('<li><a href="#exercises" id="c0">Arms</a></li>');
    $("#categoryList").append('<li><a href="#exercises" id="c1">Legs</a></li>');
    $("#categoryList").listview("refresh");
}
```

Steps to reproduce (it doesn't always happen):
1- Click on "Arms"
2- Quickly click on back button
3- Quickly click on "Arms" again

Instead of getting this:
[image: Expected result]

you get this: [image: Actual result]

Comment: There is no Arms , this is what you sent ; https://jsfiddle.net/6rvom9aw/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem mainly by changing

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
```

to

```
$(document).on('vclick', 'a', function () {
```